# Compile time error on building OBS-Studio on Windows 10

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, cmake-gui, obs-studio

I am trying to build [obs-studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) by following official steps at
https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#windows-build-directions

I used [cmake GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake)  to generate Visual Studio project. When I tried to build project in Visual Studio I am getting these errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'IsCursorCaptureEnabled': is not a member of 'winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureSession'    libobs-winrt    C:\Users\alokm\obs-studio\libobs-winrt\winrt-capture.cpp    290 

Error   C2039   'IsCursorCaptureEnabled': is not a member of 'winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureSession'    libobs-winrt    C:\Users\alokm\obs-studio\libobs-winrt\winrt-capture.cpp    372 

Error   C2039   'IsCursorCaptureEnabled': is not a member of 'winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureSession'    libobs-winrt    C:\Users\alokm\obs-studio\libobs-winrt\winrt-capture.cpp    473
```

How can I resolve these erroes?

Here is my Visual Studio details

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.4
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.8.4+30907.101
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA868
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.8.557.25636
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.8.557.25636
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   3.8.0-5.20604.10+9ed4b774d20940880de8df1ca8b07508aa01c8cd
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

NuGet Package Manager   5.8.1
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Visual Basic Tools   3.8.0-5.20604.10+9ed4b774d20940880de8df1ca8b07508aa01c8cd
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual C++ for Linux Development   1.0.9.30608
Visual C++ for Linux Development

Visual F# Tools   16.8.0-beta.20507.4+da6be68280c89131cdba2045525b80890401defd
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake
```

Comment: Why not open an issue on the project's github? https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues

Comment: I have posted on obs-studio's official forum. okay I will post issue on repo also

Answer (score 0):

Updating Windows SDK and removing obsolete versions is resolving all errors.

In Visual Studio open `Tools` > `Get Tools and Features` > `Individual components`
Search with "Windows SDK" then select latest `Windows 10 SDK` and unselect old version and then click `modify`.

[image]